# Internet Explorer, z-index, and "modality"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index, modal-dialog

The following, in Firefox 3.6, simulates a modal overlay:

```
<html>
<body>

    <div id="modal" style="position: fixed; 
        top: 0; left: 0;right: 0; bottom: 0;
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
        z-index: 10;">

        <div style="border-style:solid;border-width:5px;
                    position: fixed;top: 50%;left:50%">
           <h2>I am modal</h2>
           <form><input type=submit></form>
         </div>
    </div>


    <div id="notModal" style="height:500px;
                              border-style:solid;border-width:5px;">
        <div>
            <h2>a I am not modal</h2>
            <p>lorem ipsit dolar foo bar baz</p>
            <form><input type=submit></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In particular, text in the "modal" div can be selected, and the submit button in the "modal" div can be clicked, but nothing in the "notModal" div can be selected or clicked.

In Internet Explorer 8, that's not the case; the "notModal" text can be selected and teh "notModal" submit can be cliecked.

Is there a way to make this work under the various versions of IE, without using javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE has a lot of issues with transparency (it doesn't support `rgba`). There are also known issues with z-indexing.

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A66Wa/1/).

Notes:

- Most IE z-index issues can be fixed by applying z-indexes to the parent elements of the elements you're trying to specify a z-index for.
- I moved the modal window out of the `cover` (previously `modal`) div so that IE doesn't try to apply the filter to it.

**Example**
*HTML*

```
<div id="cover"></div>
<div id="modalbox">
   <h2>I am modal</h2>
   <form><input type=submit></form>
 </div>

<div id="notModal">
    <div>
        <h2>a I am not modal</h2>
        <p>lorem ipsit dolar foo bar baz</p>
        <form><input type=submit></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    z-index: 1;
}
#cover {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* Only applies to IE */
    background: red; /* This will be overwritten by browsers that support rgba */
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); /* IE ignores this since it's not supported */
    z-index: 10;
}
#modalbox {
    border:solid 5px #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index: 20;
}
#notModal {
    height:500px;
    border:solid 5px #ccc;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: OP here: that works (in IE 8, at least, haven't tested it against others yet), but I'm still not sure why it works. I'd previously tried a version where the body had a z-index; is the answer that everything has to have a z-index?

Comment: @tpdi: Well, part of the reason it didn't work before was because you had no background specified (as I mentioned, rgba isn't supported in IE). On top of that, there may have been some z-index issues. I put that code in there just for good measure. If you want to see a good description of the z-index bug in IE (and how to fix it), check [here](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/). Note that it doesn't necessarily require putting z-index on everything, only parents, however in this case `<body>` is the parent.

Answer (score 2):

IE won't recognize a rgba color, try to use a rgb and use filter:alpha(opacity=50)